# What is the equivalent of x[i:] in Scala?

Tags: java, python, scala, data-structures, bigdata

In Python, you can get a sublist from a certain starting index to the end using `x[i:]`, for example if `x = [1, 2, 3, 4], x[1:]` would give you `[2, 3, 4]`. I was wondering what is the equivalent way to do this in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `drop` for this case:

```
x.drop(1)
```

For the particular case of 1, we usually use `x.tail` instead.

Comment: There's an important difference between `.drop(1)` and `tail`: `tail` throws an exception on an empty collection.

Comment: Good point. I had overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `drop` and you use it like `xs.drop(i)`.